# How to store xml file data into list in C# and display on console using LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have to store data of xml file into List in c# using LING on the basis of Module name and display that data on console.Below is my XML file format.I tried lots of options but never get success. I am new to C#

```
<getMetadata>
    <Module Name="Doors_Module2">
   <Field>
<AttributeName>TableType</AttributeName>
<AttributeType>TableType</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
    <AttributeName>TableTopBorder</AttributeName>
    <AttributeType>TableEdgeType</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
   <AttributeName>TableShowWide</AttributeName>
   <AttributeType>Boolean</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
   <AttributeName>TableShowBookform</AttributeName>
   <AttributeType>Boolean</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
   <AttributeName>TableShowAttrs</AttributeName>
   <AttributeType>Boolean</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
   <AttributeName>TableRightBorder</AttributeName>
   <AttributeType>TableEdgeType</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
   <AttributeName>TableLinkIndicators</AttributeName>
   <AttributeType>Boolean</AttributeType>
</Field>
</Module>
<Module Name="Doors_Module1">

<Field>
    <AttributeName>TableType</AttributeName>
    <AttributeType>TableType</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
    <AttributeName>TableTopBorder</AttributeName>
    <AttributeType>TableEdgeType</AttributeType>
</Field>
<Field>
    <AttributeName>TableShowWide</AttributeName>
    <AttributeType>Boolean</AttributeType>
</Field>
</Module>
</getMetadata>
```

Comment: Why you want to store a xml file in a list? Your intention is to output the xml file to console? Then you do not need a list.

Comment: Smells like a homework assignment. "I tried lots of options" - what have you tried? Before asking the community for help, at least show your have put in some effort yourself. What code have you written that fails to do this?

Comment: You may be able to read into a dataset.  I can't tell how well this will work in your case because you posted only a piece of the xml.  Try :            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
public class Module
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string AttributeType { get; set; }
}

XDocument loXDocument = XDocument.Parse(lsXmlString);
var loList = (from module in loXDocument.Descendants("Module")
                let fields = module.Descendants("Field").Select(item => new Field
                {
                    AttributeName = item.Element("AttributeName").Value,
                    AttributeType = item.Element("AttributeType").Value,
                })
                select new Module
                {
                    Name = module.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    Fields = fields.ToList()
                }).ToList();

foreach (var loModule in loList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Module: {loModule.Name}");
    foreach (var loField in loModule.Fields)
        Console.WriteLine($"AttributeName: {loField.AttributeName}, AttributeType{loField.AttributeType}");
}
```